# What's the equivalent of "wget -i FILE" in Curl?

Tags: windows, wget, curl

What's the equivalent of "wget -i FILE" in Curl?

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
xargs curl < FILE
```

Comment: How to made this in Windows?

Comment: xargs is a unix command.  You probably need to use Matthew Flaschen's answer if you're looking at a windows solution.

Answer (score 1):

Token's approach is the simplest.  However, curl also has a `-K` option for a config file.  You can specify one or more URLs like:

```
url = "curl.haxx.se"
```

This can be convenient because it also allows you to set all of the other curl command-line options.  E.g.

```
output = "curlhere.html"
user-agent = "superagent/1.0"
```

See the [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows,

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (FILE) do @curl "%%i"
```